# How does this Apache environment variable syntax work?

Tags: apache, environment-variables

I've seen a bunch of examples for dynamically setting request origin headers in htaccess that all look approximately like this:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?(example\.com|example\.org)$" REQUEST_ORIGIN=$0
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e env=REQUEST_ORIGIN
```

However, I can't seem to find an explanation for the syntax of that second line anywhere. I also looked here where I found an example with similar syntax but again, nothing to explain how it works:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html

Specifically, I want to know about `%{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e` and `env=REQUEST_ORIGIN`.

What does each of those things do? The former appears to be doing something with the variable but how does the brace syntax work and why the trailing `e`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second line sets the Access-Control-Allow-Origin only if **REQUEST_ORIGIN** variable is set.

About `%{REQUEST_ORIGIN}e` it tells that it needs to grab the value from environment variable.

Basically these two lines together checks for valid/secure origins and set CORS headers to their proper values if check passes.

#### Documentation

> The Header directive may be followed by an additional argument, which may be any of:
>
> ...
>
> **env=[!]varname**
>
> The directive is applied if and only if the environment variable varname exists. A ! in front of varname reverses the test, so the directive applies only if varname is unset.

As for the `e` syntax:

> %{VARNAME}e   The contents of the environment variable VARNAME.

References:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html

Comment: Thanks.  Searching "apache environment variables" gets me the mod_env docs which lead nowhere.  Apparently mod_headers docs is what I was looking for.

Comment: I noticed that all variables enclosed in curly braces also have a letter after curly brace closure - such as `%{Referer}i` - does that letter (`i` in this case) mean anything? It is not mentioned anywhere in the Apache2 manual.

Comment: @AnthonyK as per apache's documentation, these "i" ones are values from request headers. Also, there's no single place where all of them are documented, they seem to be a per-module setting. Try looking at the specific module documentation based on which section you are on your apache config.http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html